# I take error like this, i think about tableView but i see in stack trace about FBSDK

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reminders, fbsdk

I can't find the error's reason... Help please...

```
0   CoreFoundation  CFStringCreateCopy (in CoreFoundation) + 36

1   libswiftCore.dylib  0x100a149d8 0x10094c000 + 821720

2   libswiftCore.dylib  0x1009f85b0 0x10094c000 + 705968

3   XXX_APP_NAME    XXX_APP_NAME.JSON.uInt8.setter : Swift.UInt8? (in XXX_APP_NAME  (SwiftyJSON.swift:866)

4   XXX_APP_NAME    _fbsdkCreateUpPointingBubbleWithRect (in XXX_APP_NAME) (FBSDKTooltipView.m:320)

5   XXX_APP_NAME    +[FBSDKLoginManager renewSystemCredentials:] (in XXX_APP_NAME  (FBSDKLoginManager.m:97)

6   XXX_APP_NAME    -[FBSDKTooltipView presentFromView:] (in XXX_APP_NAME) (FBSDKTooltipView.m:146)

7   XXX_APP_NAME    -[FBSDKTooltipView presentInView:withArrowPosition:direction:] (in XXX_APP_NAME  (FBSDKTooltipView.m:171)

8   CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation) + 24

9   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoSources0 (in CoreFoundation) + 264

10  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 712

11  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 396

12  GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal (in GraphicsServices) + 168

13  UIKit   UIApplicationMain (in UIKit) + 1488

14  XXX_APP_NAME    XXX_APP_NAME.AlarmListViewController.tableView (XXX_APP_NAME.AlarmListViewController)(ObjectiveC.UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath : ObjectiveC.NSIndexPath) -> ObjectiveC.UITableViewCell (in XXX_APP_NAME) (AlarmListViewController.swift:112)

15  libdyld.dylib   start (in libdyld.dylib) + 4
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks the the FBSDK is calling for some kind of tooltip object on a particular tableViewRow, but the `AlarmListViewController.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is crashing.

Since you are asking for help identifying the error in this stack trace, I would recommend that you add an **[Exception Breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html)** if you haven't done so already.  That will help you pinpoint the exact line where the error is occurring.  If that doesn't work, then try to put a breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and run the app again, stepping through the code to until you find the line and conditions causing the error.  Hope this helps!